# Fluid Header, Footer and 3 columns CS layout (Cross browser)

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

I need a CSS code and HTML for a **Cross browser** CSS layout (IE7+) with Header, footer and 3 columns (midde/left/right) middle section. I want the MAIN (see illustration) to have flexible width, but both sidebars fixed width (e.g. 200px). I don't want the sidebars to collapse down when I shrink the window.

The MAIN DIV will have a minimum width, let's say 800px.

All the elements should have fluid height.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: I tried to make a page like that for IE7 once. Then I gave up and used a table.

Comment: Have you tried anything? are you giving it as a task to SO users?

Comment: You need to read about float for DIV elements. There are hundreds of tutorials out there. Getting the middle DIV to be flexible is tricky as it'll be floated, and you have to consider where does it "flex" to? Squash or expand the two side DIVs? Not sure you reason (sure you have one) but this approach usually leads to coding and CSS nightmares. Fixed widths all the way and control what the width of the content is when you put it in the DIVs (imo, of course)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/G8cuj/ check this out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this fiddle for accordion center **http://jsfiddle.net/PduXc/7/**

for full example click here **http://jsfiddle.net/PduXc/14/**

```
body
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.sidebarleft
{
    width: 100px;
    height: 350px;
    background: red;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 7;
}

.sidebarright
{
    width: 100px;
    height: 350px;
    background: red;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 6;
}
.main
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 350px;
    background: green;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 5;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but not good. If you resize the frame you can see that the right DIV falls to the bottom.

Comment: fixed it. check again pls.

Answer (score 1):

Here's something that can help you start (basically it looks like you want us to do all the work for you).

Wrap the "main" and "sidebar" in a wrapping div, than give this div the following style:

```
.wrapper
{
    margin: auto;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px; /* Leave 50 pixels for header */
    left: 0; 
    bottom: 0; 
    right: 30px; /* Leave 30 pixels for footer */
}
```

After that you can give the inner elements { height: 100% } and it'll work.

Maybe this link will also assist you: http://codepen.io/shshaw/full/gEiDt

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure if this will help you, but first, are you wanting the header and footer to be 100% full-width of a screen?

Try this:

html:

```
<body>
    <div id="header"></div>
    <div id="sidebarA"></div>
    <div id="main"></div>
    <div id="sidebarB"></div>
    <div id="footer"></div>
</body>
```

css:

```
#header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #333; /*--Give it some color ;) --*/
  border-bottom: 2px solid #444;
}
#sidebarA {
  width: 200px;
  height: 800px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background: blue;
  float: left;
}
#main {
  width: 800px;
  height: 800px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: purple;
}
#sidebarB {
  width: 200px;
  height: 800px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  background: blue;
  float: right;
}
#footer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #333;
  border-top: 2px solid #444;
}
```

Of course all can be easily customized to your liking ;)  Give that a try and see if you like it, if anything, it's a good frame layout to start out with and tweak.

Comment: display: inline for floating element? why this?